# add time plus and recalculate the datetime

Tags: datetime

I'm new into coding.
I'm using the `echo %time%` to get the time.
Now is my goal to add 4 hours to this time and create the output.
Nice would be to have the time only in hours and minutes.

Comment: well - some small detail: do you use a programming language?

Answer (score 2):

It would help to tell you are working on a batch script, makes helping easier

You can split up the time in hours and minutes:

```
set hh=%time:~0,2%
set mm=%time:~3,2%
```

and add 4 hours:

```
set /A hh=%hh%+4
```

then concat them back together, and do not forget to fix it when the hours go above 24, a simple if statement would do fine then distract the 24 to get the right time